# Pegar dados de arrays dinamicamente em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, na qual preciso pegar de forma dinâmica os dados que estão cadastrados no banco de dados. Para ler estes dados, tenho essa função:

```
// Lê registros
function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null; // Caso não haja parâmetros, remove espaço em branco no final da Query

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if (!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Ela me retorna um `array`, com vários índices, e, dentro desses índices, vem mais um `array`, com mais índices. Exemplo de retorno:

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string 'Postagem de testes' (length=18)
          'titulo' => string 'Postagem de testes' (length=18)
          1 => string 'Welington Braga' (length=15)
          'autor' => string 'Welington Braga' (length=15)
      1 => 
          array
            0 => string 'Huheuhehue' (length=10)
            'titulo' => string 'Huheuhehue' (length=10)
            1 => string 'Welington Braga' (length=15)
            'autor' => string 'Welington Braga' (length=15)
```

Não entendo por qual motivo essa função está retornando erro:

> "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in":

```
$postagens = DBRead('postagens', 'WHERE status = 1', 'titulo, autor, conteudo');

while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($postagens)){
    echo '.$dados['titulo']'; //Imprime os dados que preciso
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Não entendo por qual motivo essa função está retornando erro "`mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, `array` given in":

A função `DBRead` retorna um `array` com os dados que você quer, não é necessário usar `mysql_fetch_array` novamente.

Faça assim:

```
$postagens = DBRead('postagens', 'WHERE status = 1', 'titulo, autor, conteudo');

if ($postagens) {
    foreach ($postagens as $postagem) {
        echo $postagem['titulo'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou como precisava xD

Answer (score 2):

Troca a função de leitura por essa:

```
// Lê registros
function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null; // Caso não haja parâmetros, remove espaço em branco no final da Query

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return $result;
    }

}
```

E o código que chama a leitura, troca por esse:

```
$postagens = DBRead('postagens', 'WHERE status = 1', 'titulo, autor, conteudo');

if($postagens != false){
while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($postagens)){
    echo $dados['titulo']; //Imprime os dados que preciso
}
}else{
echo 'Nenhum registro foi encontrado';
}
```

Comment: Solução funcional, porém, precisava que a função de leitura fosse a dada na postagem.